# Opening .csv files from Outlook in Excel

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am sent a lot of .csv files and ideally I would like these .csv files to open in Microsoft Excel rather than in Notepad. This is what used to happen. So then I can either preview them in the mail in Excel or open them straight away into Excel.

How can I make .csv files open in Microsoft Excel?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the file association on your PC. Hold down shift and right click on the .csv file, then select 'Open with...'. Select excel from the list, make sure the tick box below the selection of programs labelled 'Always open this type of file using this program' (or words to that effect) is checked, then click ok, and you will always be able to open .csv files in excel without having to go to excel first and click file/open.

Comment: This assumes a windows OS

Comment: The only other format you can get Microsoft Office is for Mac, and Mac OS' doesn't include Notepad.

Comment: This will not enable Previewer.